# Cosa sono "le bagne" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Diceva: "Politicamente analfabeti lo erano tanto i nostri generali quanto i nostri soldati. Non si sentivano aggressori. Quando cadevano nelle '**bagne** grosse', nelle '**bagne** spesse', non capivano o fingevano di non capire: assumevano sempre il ruolo della vittima. La boria fascista faceva il resto".

Quello che dice queste parole è Nuto Revelli. Malgrado abbia cercato il significato di "bagna" in alcuni dizionari, non capisco il significato di "bagne" in questo brano. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo il dizionario Hoepli (http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/B/bagna.aspx), «essere nella bagna» significa "essere nei pasticci". Le «bagne grosse» dovrebbero dunque essere i «grossi guai».